# Could one make an asymmetric encryption scheme based on Sudoku?

Tags: public-key

I was reading about a Polly Cracker encryption scheme based on the graph 3-coloring problem.  Aren't Latin squares just a form of the same problem?  If so, does this mean Sudoku can be used for public/private key encryption?

Comment: Yes, and I am sure it is even used as an example in one of the crypto materials that I read - I'll be danged if I know the source though. Of course, a 9x9 Sudoku would not work; you'd have to greatly expand the dimensions. My Sudoku solver program can solve any *evil rated* 9x9 Sudoku in 0.1 seconds, and that's just the startup time of the Java VM - not the calculation itself.

Comment: Dang, I would have liked to read your source :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. How efficient vs secure is another matter.

Look up Merkle's puzzles, as well. A latin square as a higher dimensional object can be related to differential properties of good mappings.

Comment: Would you have any sources that describe how to actually implement a Sudoku (or any Latin square) as an asymmetric encryption scheme?  I only have a vague notion of how it would work.